# Error message: I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I'm working from Linux Mint.  When I try to compile a basic LaTeX document like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
  Test text.
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
$ pdflatex hw1.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt line 25.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

Based on another question on StackExchange, which led to this link

http://verahill.blogspot.com/2012/04/solved-latex-bug-tcfmgr-config-file.html

I tried this solution, but it failed:

```
$ sudo texconfig rehash
sudo: texconfig: command not found
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with how I set up the TeX tree.  I initially didn't set one up and that worked fine for years.  But then I needed to install a package, and came to find out that you have to do some kind of a weird tree setup.  So I did it the best I could, but I think I screwed it up some how, because soon after that I started getting this error.  But because I had another computer I could work from, and I had a time deadline, I just used my other computer and never installed the needed package and just tried to work around it.

But that old computer is dead now, so I have to get TeX working on this computer, and I'm very lost in how to set up TeX the right way.

Comment: The pdfTeX version says it's from Debian's TeX Live 2017, but the path to `mktexfmt` looks like you tried to install a vanilla TeX Live. Did you really manually install TeX Live over the distribution version?

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz That sounds probably like what I did.  I know I just used `apt` to install TeX originally, but then realized that I couldn't install certain packages that way.  Looked around for online instructions on how to install packages, tried to follow them as best I could.  I believe that led me to installing another version of LaTeX.

Comment: In that case remove the TeX Live you installed via `apt`. Check that your `PATH` variable is correctly set (it should include the `bin` folder of your vanilla TeX Live installation, that should be `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/`).